# Error en ng new angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

hola colegas tengo un problema al intentar ejecutar el comando ng new este es el comando tal cuál como siempre lo he ejecutado para generar un proyecto nuevo "ng new projectname -S --routing=true --style=css --strict=true" y me arroja el siguiente error

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.7.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/mcutino/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mcutino/.npm/_logs/2021-05-10T15_09_52_304Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Comment: Te dice que este paquete `jasmine-core@3.6.0` es inferior al que te pide el nuevo proyecto. Es decir, cuando creas el proyecto, angular te pide que sea la version `jasmine-core@">=3.7.1"` o superior.. Intenta con un `npm update` para que se actualice todo de manera global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entra en la carpeta que has creado con el CLI y modifica el archivo `package.json`.

En la dependencia `jasmine-core`, cambia la versión a 3.7.1

En `karma-jasmine-html-reporter` ponla en 1.6.0

Ejecuta `npm i` o `npm install` y cruza los dedos.

Comment: En mi caso fue 3.8 y el reporter 1.7 en el mismo mensaje de error indica cual instalar o ejecutar con el npm i