# angular unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: angular

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: mitienda@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.7.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/andresbetancur/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Comment: Y cómo está el package.json?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error en ng new angular cli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/450769/error-en-ng-new-angular-cli)

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente el error se debe a que tienes un par de dependencias que no funcionan con la version de Node que tienes, una forma de resolverlo permanentemente es instalar una version de Node anterior pero a veces es complicado saber cual es la indicada para cada caso, otra forma seria instalar las versiones legacy de las dependencias que tienes para de esa forma evitar el error.

Elimina tu carpeta de node_modules y despues ejecuta el siguiente comando.

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Despues de esto vuelve a correr el proyecto y todo deberia de funcionar sin problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Ayer respondí a un problema exactamente igual, por favor echa un vistazo en el buscador antes de formular una pregunta.

Abre el package.json que ha generado el CLI y modifica lo siguiente:

`jasmine-core` versión `3.7.1` 
`karma-jasmine-html-reporter` versión `1.6.0`

El enlace: [Error en ng new angular cli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/450769/error-en-ng-new-angular-cli/450774#450774)